# How does Google Application - "Keep Notes" work even after device reboot for reminders?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I would like to run this reminder even after device reboot, but it's not working for miui devices. But, the same works with Google Application - "Keep Notes" even after reboot. Why ?

Comment: How have you created the reminder? When the device reboots all alarms scheduled with `AlarmManager` are deleted and you will need to reschedule them yourself.

Comment: I have used Work Manager to schedule tasks

Answer (score 0):

On some devices you need to manually add your app to the list of apps that ate allowed to run in the background or the list of apps allowed to start at boot. Sometimes these are called "protected" apps. Usually there is a way to add your app in Settings->battery. Search for this for your specific device. If you don't add your app to this list, Android won't restart or launxh your app after reboot.